# Menu white line above the lists

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I have been working on this site **[MY SITE](http://constantin-entertainment.info/hd2wallpapers)** for a quite days.I used **UBER menu plugin** to display my menu in more a custom way and is working fine.But when it is displaying it shows a thin white line above the menu item.I added the following css which didn't help

```
border-top:none !important;
```

Some one please help me please.Thanks :) !!!

Comment: attach your css and html codes

Comment: why so many css overridings?

Comment: i think you must add this codes to your menu: `border-size:0px` and `border-color:blue` ... this is very stupid solved ... if you attach all of codes, we can to answer this question

Comment: sorry ... **we can** :)

Comment: to which class shud i add this?

Comment: attach your css codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following css have the transparent background color.

```
 #megaMenu li.menu-item
 {
  background-color:transparent;
 }
```

Apply the same menu background to this class. it will fix the issue.

```
 #megaMenu li.menu-item
 {
  background-color:#606b9a;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try css command `vertical-align` as below:

`vertical-align:top`

Hope this may help to resolve your query.

Answer (score 1):

It is a white ***box-shadow*** on `#megaMenu` div, to remove it use

```
box-shadow:none;
-webkit-box-shadow:none;
```